# Equivalent command for PowerShell with this Unix command

Tags: node.js, powershell, unix, machine-learning

I'm trying to reproduce a simple spam filter using naive bayes and Node.js on windows, I got a resource with these Unix commands and don't know how to run it on PowerShell:

`sed -nr 's#^0 (.*)#training/\1#p' CSDMC2010_SPAM/CSDMC2010_SPAM/SPAMTrain.label | xargs node spamfilter.js -s`

`sed -nr 's#^1 (.*)#training/\1#p' CSDMC2010_SPAM/CSDMC2010_SPAM/SPAMTrain.label | xargs node spamfilter.js -h`

SPAMTrain.label is a file contains training files' name and label (0 for spam and 1 for non-spam), after some searching, I know that `sed` command is used to replace text and `xargs` is used to bash.
So I think these commands will figure out which TRAINING files are spam and which are non-spam.
`-s`, `-h` are arguments I pass in to run the spamfilter.js

Is there any way I can run these 2 commands on PowerShell, or rewrite it to fit PowerShell command line?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`select-string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) in the powershell for `sed` in linux
and [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-Expression?view=powershell-6) for `xargs`